# Adding shapefile elevation data to dted

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation, dted

I am a newbie to QGIS. Currently trying to augment a dted raster value file with vector shapefile(polygon) containing height of buildings.

Have converted the shapefile into raster via rasterize function. WheneverI mouse over the converted shapefile(now raster), I am able to get the value of the polygonal shape (from the band value) corresponding to the old shapefile polygon elevation

For the dted, the mouseover seem to give me the quantized color depth(band value). How could we get the real height value? Or display them?

Lastly, how do we add the two values together and merge them into a single raster data set. I have already projected them to use the same reference coordinate system

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generically...
Convert the vector file to raster using the appropriate field
Ensure that the extent and cell size of the output matches the raster file in the process
reclass the NoData values to 0
add to combine the two files

Comment: Apologies. Quite new to QGIS function. How do you add them together? using Raster Calculator? My dted band seem to give me te band value and not the height.  Anyway this is what I have done, I have converted the vector to raster using Raster->Conversion->Rasterize (with the fields I need). Then I fill the nodata field with Raster->Analysis->Fill nodata. I am having some problems with the adding part as mentioned earlier

Comment: oops! Realise my mistake... A dted raster band shows its height value! I am using the raster calculator to add the layer together...Thanks for your help!